# Labeling and refrencing chemistry equations with oxidation

Tags: cross-referencing, chemistry, chemmacros

Im working with some chemistry where oxidation numbers are displayed in reactions

im having a hard time getting the reactions labeled with a number i can then refrence later

I'm using `chemmacros` and `cleveref`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{report}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}
\chemsetup[redox]{pos=top}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{chemistry}
     \ox{3,S_2}O_4^{2-}(aq)+4OH^-(aq)\rightleftharpoons 2\ox{4,S}O^{2-}(aq)+2e^-+2H_2O(l)
     \label{redox_1} %the label serves no function right now
\end{chemistry}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

if i have a `begin{reaction}` enviroment where the labeling and refrencing works fine, but the `\ox` commando screws my code up
I have also tried `\begin{redox}`(because chemmacros have a redox module) but that doesnt work either

i have looked in the chemmacros PDF for a long time but can't find any help

Comment: Put the `\ox{...}` between `"..." ` and put spaces around

Comment: like this?
 ```"\ox{3,S_2}"```
if yes, it wont work, the PDF-displaying goes crazy

Comment: i have reviewed my own code and it seems to work now, thak you